# Based on gravity a question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

If a tunnel is dug by some people along the diameter  of earth and then a ball is thrown through it starting from North Pole  to  South Pole  whether it

A) stops at center

B) comes to the other pole and stop

C) goes out of tunnel.

D) it just moves up and down.

Comment: Physics Stack Exchange isn't a homework help site; but, if you do want that kind of help you can take a look at [this thread for a list of free online homework help resources](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/391/my-question-was-closed-on-phys-se-can-you-recommend-me-another-internet-site-wh).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that only gravity acts on the ball, it would arrive at the South Pole with the same velocity as it had in the beginning, so if the ball was thrown, it had $v_{i} \neq 0$ which means that $v_{f} \neq 0$. So C is the correct answer.

Comment: I don't know why this is down-voted.  Whiile there isn't much explanation as to *why* this is the correct answer. It is correct.  But it won't keep going "out."  It will eventually stop and fall back toward the hole.  All this is assuming a spherical, angularly-uniform earth where the density is only radially dependent.

Comment: @BillN: my guess is that since it's an answer to a lazy homework question (which we discourage) the downvote is a sign to not answer it.

Comment: @BillN Well it does depend on the initial velocity, if it will continue going "out" or fall back.

Comment: @Kyle Kanos Oh, I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: I doubt that someone could throw the ball with Earth's escape velocity.  It will eventually stop and turn around, just as if you threw the ball upward.

Comment: Isn't D the correct answer?

Comment: Well yeah no one would be able to throw it that hard but it's a hypothetical problem (no wind resistance and all) so it can be assumed.